# One quick question about Moore–Penrose inverse of a symmetric matrix

Tags: pseudoinverse

I was wondering whether the following equation is correct, and why if so. Here the $
\left( A\right)^{+}   
$ is the MP inverse of matrix A.

$$
\left(A^{\top} A\right)^{+}A^{\top}  =\lim _{\rho \rightarrow 0}\left(A^{\top} A+\rho I\right)^{-1} A^{\top}
$$

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, if
$$
A:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then the limit does not exist.

Comment: You are right. My bad. I was not stating the quetion right. I will revise it. Thank you .